# facebook javascript feed/send onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following js from facebook which simply loads either a feed or send dialog depending on method setting.

It loads it on page load. Can it be instead loaded on click? Meaning when a user wants it rather than when the page loads?

Example js

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  // assume we are already logged in
  FB.init({appId: '123456', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

  FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
      link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: Of course it can be called on click – what’s your actual problem with that? Wrap it inside a function, and set this function as the event handler for the element(s) you like … using some framework like jQuery for convenience, or the “old-fashioned” pure JS style, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not! Serve the API inside a function and execute the function on click of an anchor tag.

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/N9jhL/

Comment: Thanks so much for that, however, do i have to wrap it in something to load it? When i copy what you kindly wrote, and included jquery, nothing happens, but I see onLoad set on the fiddle and wonder how to translate that to my code. Thanks for your help, new to js.

Comment: After you've included jQuery, wrap the piece of JavaScript code from fiddle inside the jQuery DOM ready function: `$(function(){ \\ Insert code here });`. You'll then need to attach the `loadFB` function to an event on an element. In my case, I have bound this function to a `click` handler on an anchor tag. You can replace the `$('a')` part of the code with the specific element upon which the click is required.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - I've updated my fiddle with comments for a bit more explaination.